# facebook getLogoutUrl() not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I try for hours now to fix this issue but i found nothing.

the link with getLogoutUrl() of the php facebook SDK is generated but when i click it only redirect me to facebook home page without logout or redirect...

Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you include the access token in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it done like this

```
if ($facebook->getUser()) {
               $logoutParams = array('next'  =>  '/users/logout/');
               echo '<li><a href="'.$logoutUrl.'" ">facebook logout</a></li></ul></li>';
                          }
```

Comment: I found the solution thank you! I wrote the link by myself and not with the SDK and it works now

Comment: Do you mean that originally you wrote it yourself, and it didn't work, and now you are using the SDK and it does work? If the answer is YES, then all well and good. But if you mean you originally used the SDK but now you have written your own, then don't do that. Instead, stick to the SDK and find out why it wasn't working. Otherwise you are just creating future problems for yourself.